# How can I create Custom Error messages using JSRuntime?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, blazor

I am a little confused about error messages. I've read a lot on the internet and the simplest thing I would like to implement seems to be JSRuntime in Blazor serverside application. I want basically an error prompt that will show custom messages on my page, depending on the input. I've read [this](https://chrissainty.com/using-javascript-interop-in-razor-components-and-blazor/) article and played a little:

```
@page "/sayhello"

@inject IJSRuntime jsRuntime



<h3>Do you want to say hello?</h3>
<br />

<table style="width:100%">
    <tr>
        <td><label>yes?:</label></td>
        <td><InputCheckbox id="yesplease" @bind-Value="yes" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><label>no?:</label></td>
        <td><InputCheckbox id="nothankyou" @bind-Value="no" /></td>
    </tr>

</table>

<button @onclick="CheckInput">Tell me</button>

@code {

    string message = "";
    private bool yes = false;
    private bool no = false;

    private async Task ShowAlert()
    {
        await jsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("ShowAlert", message);
    }

    private void CheckInput()
    {
        if (yes)
        {
            message = "Hello";
        }
        else if (no)
        {
            message = "Don't talk to me";
        }
        else
        {
            message = "I am not sure";
        }
        ShowAlert();
    }

}
```

There is no prompt showing up and I don't understand why? Also, the compiler is throwing

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Warning CS4014  Because this call is not awaited, execution of the current method continues before the call is completed. Consider applying the 'await' operator to the result of the call.

But I do await?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, you must place the `InputCheckbox` within an EditForm component
Secondly, you should use only a single InputCheckbox component, not two. Ordinarily the InputCheckbox enable two states: checked (true) and unchecked (false)

You may define a Boolean variable which you bind to the value attribute of the check box as follows:

```
@code
{
   private bool selectedValue;
   string message = "";

   private bool SelectedValue
   {
     get => selectedValue;
     set 
    {
        if ( selectedValue == value) return;
        selectedValue = value; 
        CheckInput();
    }
     
   }
    private void CheckInput()
    {
       if (SelectedValue)
       {
            message = "Display alert only when the check box was ticked";
           _ = ShowAlert(message );
       }
    }

    private async Task ShowAlert(string message)
    {
        await jsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("ShowAlert", message);
    }
}
```

And this is how you bind to the InputCheckbox

```
<InputCheckbox id="yesplease" @bind-Value="SelectedValue" />
```

Don't forget to put it in an EditForm.

Question: Did you define a JavaScript function named `ShowAlert` ? I ask this question as I did not see its code here. If you did not, then you should.

However, I guess this should work:

```
await jsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("window.alert", message);
```

Note: This code was typed here without being executed by me... Please, report of any errors.

Comment: No, I didn't write JavaScript function named `ShowAlert`. I thought this was a function which is available... Using "window.alert" worked for me! 
But a question: why shouldn't I use two checkboxes? Or do you mean one checkbox in one `EditForm`? It seems quite handy to me as I am able to set messages depending on the users input and all a single `ShowAlert`

Comment: You may use as many check boxes as you like, but then you should use them appropriately and effectively. As the check box normally has two states, I believe that one check box is sufficient for "yes" and "no" states. If you think your design requires two, then go ahead and use two. It's free.